# API Twitter console returning bad JSON

Tags: json, api, twitter

I'd like to try to use Twitter API console for a non-programmers course, and I was preparing a pipeline with API console, jq play and so on. However, I've found that the JSON returned by the API console is bad-formed, like this
[image]
Basically, it's not doing anything with quotes inside the text of a tweet, not escaping them, not using single quotes for the JSON text, or anything like that. I could fix that programatically, but the problem would be, well, I'd had to go into the command line. Any tick I could mark in the API console or any other way to extract this info? Maybe through a Chrome or Firefox plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather from this post in the Twitter fora https://twittercommunity.com/t/invalid-json/12043/7 the Twitter API console is not actually intended for production purposes, it's just there to check API features and maybe demonstration and/or teaching. If you want to use the returned JSON for anything, use API apps such as Postman or consume it programatically with TweePy or any other library.